# Blur ViewGroup excluding one View

Tags: android, blur, blurry, android-viewgroup

I'm using [Blurry](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry) library to achieve the effect of blurred screen.

How can I blur whole `ViewGroup` but except of one, particular `View`?
I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to the following:

[image]

Comment: Have u got any solution?